# ESLint rule conflicts with Prettier rule

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, eslintrc, prettier-eslint

I am totally new to VSCode and this is my first setting. I know that this is a very common problem but I couldn't find a suitable solution for it.

This is my understanding so far. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I want to use ESLint for finding errors in Javascript code and Prettier for formatting all languges. But it seems that we could also format our javascript code with ESLint! There are some useful rules that I like to use it and it seems Prettier don't have those like ( space-in-parens ).

So I decided to use ESLint as my formatter in Javascript. Now I can see that there are a lot of tutorial for "How to integrates ESLint with Prettier" in web. The idea is to extend Prettier rules with a plugin and add those ESLint specific rules to it. Reasonable!

I ended up with the following settings. Please take a look at my settings for using ESLint and Prettier below:

**.eslintrc.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es6: true,
    },
    extends: ["prettier"],
    globals: {
        Atomics: "readonly",
        SharedArrayBuffer: "readonly",
    },
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2018,
        sourceType: "module",
    },
    plugins: [
        "prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "space-in-parens": ["error", "always"],
        "quotes": ["error", "single"],
        "prettier/prettier": "error"
    }
};
```

VSCode's **settings.json**

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": [
        "-l"
    ],
    "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
        "dev-all": "linux"
    },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
    // turn it off for JS and JSX, we will do this via eslint
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false
    },
    // tell the ESLint plugin to run on save
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": true
    },
    // Optional BUT IMPORTANT: If you have the prettier extension enabled for other languages like CSS and HTML, turn it off for JS since we are doing it through Eslint already
    "prettier.disableLanguages": [
        "javascript"
    ]
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
    "name": "web",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
        "prettier": "^2.0.4"
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that whenever I save my javascript code, formatting toggles! for example with the first save, I have "single quote" and with the next save I have "double quote". I thinks my understanding of the whole idea is wrong. Could you explain it for me and tell me how to correct it. I am spending so much time to figure it. By the way, I have also installed two extensions in vscode: "ESLint" and "Prettier".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have decided to let ESLint do formatting for me in JavaScript and prettier for all other languages. You could find my setting [on my git](https://github.com/Rezakarimi66/VSCode-Settings).

Answer (score 8):

This is potentially because of conflicting rules between ESLint and Prettier plugins. Now you have two options

1. Either let ESLint know that you want to use Prettier as a formatter.

https://dev.to/s2engineers/how-to-make-eslint-work-with-prettier-avoiding-conflicts-and-problems-57pi

2.You can configure ESlint and Prettier together and resolve the conflicting
rules without any conflicts.
https://blog.theodo.com/2019/08/empower-your-dev-environment-with-eslint-prettier-and-editorconfig-with-no-conflicts/

Answer (score 7):

## To solve conflict

install eslint configuration for prettier

```
npm install eslint-config-prettier
```

And include it in the `extends` option in the file `.eslintrc.js`

```
extends: [
  ...,
  "prettier",
],
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what was missing in my config :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [these settings](https://github.com/learnwithsumit/think-in-a-react-way/tree/lesson-3) by Sumit Saha. Your conflicting will be gone. These settings give more power to eslint over prettier. I am copy-pasting those.

In the ***.vscode/settings.json*** file :

```
{
  // config related to code formatting
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": null
  },
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": null
  },
  "javascript.validate.enable": false, //disable all built-in syntax checking
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    "source.fixAll.tslint": true,
    "source.organizeImports": true
  },
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  // emmet
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  }
}
```

And, in the ***.eslintrc*** file:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb/hooks",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 0,
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "no-console": 0,
    "react/state-in-constructor": 0,
    "indent": 0,
    "linebreak-style": 0,
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": 0,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      1,
      {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
      }
    ],
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "trailingComma": "es5",
        "singleQuote": true,
        "printWidth": 100,
        "tabWidth": 4,
        "semi": true,
        "endOfLine": "auto"
      }
    ]
  },
  "plugins": ["prettier", "react", "react-hooks"]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Well, I am happy with TSLint along with ESLint.
And I have a habit of doing Ctrl+Shift+F often during writing code.
Also, you can try indent-rainbow, bracket pair colorizer and my favourite, peacock.

Comment: I have those extensions, but I am writing more javascript so tslint is not suitable for me. But thanks for your sugestion. :)